# Error while using str.contains for checking numeric values in a column using regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, numeric, python-re

I have a dataframe. I want to check if a particular column has numeric values or not using regex matching. When I use `str.contains` it shows an error like below. What is the correct way to check if all the values in a column have numeric values or not?

```
df= 
 Roll.No  Words 
  20       two
  30       three
  40       four
  50       five
  60       Nan
  70       Nan
df = df[df['Roll.No'].str.contains(r'[^0-9]', na=True)]
Error: AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!
```

Comment: Looks like the `Roll.No` is a numeric column. What are you trying to find there? Dots and commas? Cast it to str then, `df[df['Roll.No'].astype(str).str.contains(r'[^0-9]', na=True)]`

Comment: Yes. If there are special characters or string values the code which I pasted will work. I just want to check if a column has only numeric value no matter if the column has numeric or special characters. If a special character or string values are present they should drop and if there are no special characters or string values they should remain the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
df = df[df['Roll.No'].astype(str).str.contains(r'[^0-9]', na=True)]
```

With `.astype(str)`, you will be able to run a regex on the numeric column.

The `.str.contains(r'[^0-9]', na=True)` expression will find all values that contain at least one char that is not a digit (like dots or commas).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what if the column has null values and I don't want to filter them out? should na= False? I tried to do it but it is filtering null values as well.

Comment: @kristintamas What do you mean by `null`? `np.nan`?

Comment: The Nan values. Rows which have no value

Comment: @kristintamas You'd probably want to convert all `nan`s into empty strings first. `df = df.fillna('')`. Or, `df = df[df['Roll.No'].astype(str).fillna('').str.contains(r'[^0-9]', na=True)]`

Comment: Yes, This is it.Thanks